# cannot apply drop shadow in IE11

Tags: html, css, svg, filter, internet-explorer-11

how can i show in internet explorer 11 the same shadow that I can apply in chrome using this rule?

```
    filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
```

This is my working chrome markup HTML

```
<div class="cta-image-container">
<div>
    <svg class="svg-cta-image">
        <image filter="url(#dropshadow)" width="640" height="580" class="cta-image cta-image-1-3" xlink:href="https://anekitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-viaggia-split.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <svg class="svg-cta-image">
        <image width="640" height="580" class="cta-image cta-image-2-3" xlink:href="https://anekitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-viaggia-split.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <svg class="svg-cta-image">
        <image width="640" height="580" class="cta-image cta-image-3-3" xlink:href="https://anekitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-viaggia-split.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="split-1-3">
            <polygon points="222,580 0,580 0.12,0 176,0"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="split-2-3">
            <polygon points="400,0 196,0 242,580 446,580"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="split-3-3">
            <polygon points="640,0 420,0 466,580 640,580"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

and this is the CSS

```
.cta-image-container svg{
    position: absolute;
}
.cta-image-container {
    width: 640px;
    height: 580px;
    margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
    filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    position: relative;
}
.cta-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.svg-cta-image {
    width: 640px;
    height: 580px;
}
.cta-image-1-3 {
clip-path: url(#split-1-3);
}
.cta-image-2-3 {
clip-path: url(#split-2-3);
}
.cta-image-3-3 {
clip-path: url(#split-3-3);
}
```

Here you can find a chrome working [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/wassilis-vasellino/pen/jOPargE?editors=1100)

Comment: drop-shadow is not supported on IE, try the search to find an alternative. https://caniuse.com/#search=drop-shadow

Comment: there is a lot of documentation about making the filters part of the svg, but I cannot fix this. Here i a great tutorial https://www.broken-links.com/2013/11/20/cross-browser-filters-css-svg/ and here an example of a shadow working in ie11 http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg but I cannot aply this fix to my markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [rx2347](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12325015/rx2347) pointed out, [IE does not support CSS Filter Effects](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

So the only way to add a drop shadow is apply the effect inside your svg by using a blurred black polygon positioned behind the image.

This is an updated version of your codepen with the applied effect https://codepen.io/samwalker/pen/XWbzpZX

I don’t have a PC/IE 11 so I used BrowserStack to test and the results below:
[image: Screenshot of Windows 8.1 ie 11]
Notes:

**1.** I had to increase the size of the viewbox/svg so the shadow wasn’t clipped

`<svg class="svg-cta-image" viewBox="0 0 660 600">`

**2.** Created the `feGaussianBlur` as an svg filter `def`.

```
<filter id="blurFilter">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
<filter />
```

The 'blur size' is set by the `stdDeviation` attr.

A good tool to show what is possible with IE filters is [Hands on: SVG filter Effects](https://testdrive-archive.azurewebsites.net/graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm)  it’s part of Azure websites & shows MS IE compatible filters

---

**3.** Created a group element inside the SVG the same shape as clip-path, this is our 'shadow'

```
 <g id="shadow" fill="black" filter="url(#blurFilter)" fill-opacity="0.5">
    <polygon points="222,580 10,580 10,10 176,10"></polygon>
    <polygon points="400,10 196,10 242,580 446,580"></polygon>
    <polygon points="640,10 420,10 466,580 640,580"></polygon>
 </g>
```

The shadow’s style is set with `fill` colour and `fill-opacity`.

I had to offset the polygon’s start points by `10px` to match the new position of the image.

---

**4.** Combined the 3 `polygons` into a single clipping path so you only need to load the image once. If you are going to use 3 different images you can easily change this back.

---

**5.** Offset the image from the edge of the svg box and reset it’s size `x="10" y="10" width="640" height="580"`, you maybe want to do this in the css.

---

There are probably some changes you’ll want to make but hopefully this will get you on the right path.

Full markup below:

```css
.cta-image-container {
  width: 660px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-image-container">
  <div>
    <svg class="svg-cta-image" viewBox="0 0 660 600"><!-- increased veiwbox by 20px so shadow isn’t clipped -->
      <defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <clipPath id="split-in-3"><!-- combined clipping path -->
          <polygon points="222,580 0,580 0.12,0 176,0"></polygon>
          <polygon points="400,0 196,0 242,580 446,580"></polygon>
          <polygon points="640,0 420,0 466,580 640,580"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
        <filter id="blurFilter">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" /><!-- size of shadow -->
        <filter />
      </defs>
      <g id="shadow" fill="black" filter="url(#blurFilter)" fill-opacity="0.5"><!-- `fill` & `fill-opacity` set the shadow’s color -->
        <polygon points="222,580 10,580 10,10 176,10"></polygon><!--`0`s replaced by 10 to offset shadow from edge of svg -->
        <polygon points="400,10 196,10 242,580 446,580"></polygon>
        <polygon points="640,10 420,10 466,580 640,580"></polygon>
      </g>
            
      <image clip-path="url(#split-in-3)" x="10" y="10" width="640" height="580" class="cta-image cta-image-1-3" xlink:href="https://anekitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-viaggia-split.jpg"></image><!-- positioned at 10px `x` & `y` to offset from edge of svg --><!-- reset size to match original -->
            
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a genius, this is working perfectly and your explanation wa so clear!!! thank you so much